# loop over a multi-dimensional list and create a separate json object from elements in Python

Tags: python, json, loops, dictionary, terraform

I have a list of data:

```
data = [['domain', '600', '10.0.0.1'],['domain2', '600', '10.0.0.2'],['domain3', '200', '10.0.0.3']]
```

I want to take this data and use it to create a terraform file in json format like so:

```
{
 "resource": 
     { "aws_route53_record": {
         "recordname": {
              "zone_id": "",
              "name": data[0][0],  # --> takes 'domain' from the data list and inputs it here
              "type": data[0][1], # --> takes '600' etc
              "ttl": data[0][2]
               # rest of code
            }

       }

 }
```

I need to create quite a few of these objects but the strings will remain the same for each one.

For reference and to make more sense of the example, please see the Terraform JSON syntax guide [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/syntax.html) and a guide on creating a route53 record via Terraform can be found [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/route53_record.html)

Once I've created that first JSON object from the first index in the list, I will then want to move on to `data[1][x]`

I'm pretty much beginner level still at Python so I hope this is enough info to go on

Just as a test I tried this:

```
for item in data:
   print(item[0])
```

which prints:

```
['domain', '600', '10.0.0.1']
['domain2', '600', '10.0.0.2']
```

as you might expect. But where I'm failing is if I do the following to print of each ttl value (index 1)

```
for item in data:
    print(item[1])
```

It will print the list of ttl numbers but will come up with an `indexError: list item out of range`:

```
'600'
'600'
'200'
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

and if I try `print(item[2])` it errors straight away.

because I get these indexErrors I'm stuck on how to access the correct info within each index

Comment: I have added some more info that should help

Comment: Does each list inside of `data` list have at least 3 items?

Comment: That is a very good question. I am working with a very large text file which I'm converting to a list. I have noticed that not every list has the same number of items.

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating through data and checking if each item has at least required number of elements.

Something like this:

```
result = []
for item in data:
    dict = {
     "resource": 
         { "aws_route53_record": {
             "recordname": {
                  "zone_id": "",
                  "name": item[0] if len(item) > 0 else "",  # --> takes 'domain' from the data list and inputs it here
                  "type": item[1] if len(item) > 1 else "", # --> takes '600' etc
                  "ttl": item[2] if len(item) > 2 else ""
                   # rest of code
                }

           }

     }
     result.append(dict)
```

Comment: Or even better, I have tidied up my txt file so every line has the same number of columns. Works perfectly now without having to put in any extra logic.
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though.